# real analysis problem(countinuous, rational and irrational problem)

Tags: real-analysis

a) Give an example of a continuous, non-constant function $f$ such that for each $x$, $f(x)$ is a rational number, or prove that no such example exists.

b) Give an example of a continuous, non-constant function $f$ such that for each $x$, $f(x)$ is an irrational number, or prove that no such example exists.

i am no cite for this one problem.
please help
thanks a lot

Comment: Cheeky answer: Define $f : (-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ by $f(x) = -2$ if $x < 0$ and $f(x) = 2$ if $x > 0$. For the second question, replace $2$ by $\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: [Intermediate Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982063/having-difficulties-showing-the-triangle-inequality-of-metric-in-the-plane  Can you help me with this question? I will award you the 350 bounty. I trust you. thanks.

Comment: @FromCuba: I’m sorry: I only just noticed this. (Somehow I missed the notification.) I’ve just added an answer; let me know if it’s sufficient.